# Старое приложение не полностью выводит интерфейс

Tags: exe

Я не владею программированием (однако есть опыт прошлых лет написания программ MSDOS на ассемблере 1992...гг ). Имеется приложение, которое при данном разрешении монитора не выводит весь интерфейс по вертикали. Нижняя часть подрезана. Доступными средствами (как-то масштабирование в настройках компьютера, изменение в свойствах файла DPI, и т.д.) добиться результата правильного отображения интерфейса не удаётся. Оно и понятно - приложение явно старое, и подразумевалось использоваться явно на мониторах более высокого разрешения.

Вопрос: сможет-ли кто-нибудь помочь изменить в самом EXE файле(соответственно его дизассемблируя, либо в другой удобочитаемы язык(?) ) задание установки размера интерфейса, если таковое возможно?

PS: файл не является вредоносным, используется в авиасимуляторе [AFRE2 Real schedule importer](https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/topic/85796-afre2-real-schedule-importer-for-wt3/)

Сам файл: [Портативная версия, важен EXE](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/L2pAOxgc19t5cA)

Скрин экрана: [Скрин](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/kdoCmTWRDWBnLw)